# ReactPaginate update issue

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I'm creating **pagination** in React (using NPM 'ReactPaginate'). When I'm changing pages, on first change page displays next 5 items, but on second change (click on the next page button/number) only displays one more item. and so on (& doesn't even shows the final items). Is it Hooks update issue? How to solve? Thanks in advance :)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const arrayNums = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
  ];

  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [perPage] = useState(5);
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);

  const getData = () => {
    const data = arrayNums;
    const slice = data.slice(offset, offset + perPage);
    const display = slice.map((i) => <p key={i}>{i}</p>);
    setData(display);
    setPageCount(Math.ceil(data.length / perPage));
  };

  const pgClick = (e) => {
    const selected = e.selected;
    setOffset(selected + (perPage - 1));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [offset]);

  return (
    <div>
      {data}
      <ReactPaginate
        previousLabel={'prev'}
        nextLabel={'next'}
        breakLabel={'...'}
        breakClassName={'break-me'}
        pageCount={pageCount}
        marginPagesDisplayed={2}
        pageRangeDisplayed={5}
        onPageChange={pgClick}
        containerClassName={'pagination'}
        subContainerClassName={'pages pagination'}
        activeClassName={'active'}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: following the pgClick logic... if i were to click on page three this is what would happen. `3 + (5 - 1) = 7`. So your offset would start at 7 instead of 15 ( page 3 * 5 items per page). I would start there

Comment: Changed **setOffset** to (data.length * perPage) and worked. Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just writing this as an answer it seems to have gotten you on the right track

following the pgClick logic... if i were to click on page three this is what would happen. 3 + (5 - 1) = 7. So your offset would start at 7 instead of 15 ( page 3 * 5 items per page). I would start there